# CollectionView with multiple cell types

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a collectionView, where each 5th cell must be different than others.

i have write the following code:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    if ((indexPath.row + 1) % 5  == 0) {

        return CGSizeMake(screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height/5);

    }
      return CGSizeMake(screenRect.size.width/2, screenRect.size.height/2);
 }




- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ((indexPath.row + 1) % 5 == 0 ) {
        NSLog(@"iAdCellWithIndex:%ld", (long)indexPath.row);
        CustomCollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (!cell)
            cell = [[CustomCollectionViewCell alloc] init];

        return cell;

    }


  ImageThumbCell * cell1 = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ImageCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  if (!cell1)
      cell1 = [[ImageThumbCell alloc] init];
  [cell1 setResultElement:intermediateResults_[indexPath.row]];

  return cell1;

  }
```

1-st cycle (first 5 elements) appear well, but then is loading 6-th element I get an exception :

```
MyApp[1503:888411] -[CustomCollectionViewCell resultElement]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a9882a0
```

I dont understand - Why ? the 6-th cell (cell at index 5)  must be kind of ImageThumbCell class, not CustomCollectionView class.

can anyone explain this mistake ?

//  sorry for bad english. i'm learning, honestly :) 
// thanks

Comment: forgot to say - collectionView without customCell is working well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is calling the setResultElement method, not resultElement. Thus that code shouldn't generate the crash you're seeing.

Your code for creating cells seems reasonable. On every 5th cell you try to dequeue a different type of cell, and if none are available, you alloc/init that other cell type. That makes sense.

My guess is that your bug is somewhere else in your code. Are you trying to read the value of your cell's resultElement property somewhere else?

Comment: I  really have not seen the difference in method names. I have in other class method 'setVisibleCells' that are setting the ' resultElement' property. solved by adding condition to this method. Thank you

Comment: You need to be clear on terms. Defining a read/write property resultElement creates 2 different methods, `-resultElement` and `-setResultElement`. The first is the getter method and the second is the setter method, both for the property resultElement.